# Effect of removing duplicates on Random Forest Regression

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I have a dataset with several million samples that have 5 features and 1 target, which I am using for a regression model.  With very large sample counts some models (like Random Forests) become very large (several GB when pickled).

These data often have duplicates or near duplicates - these are real observations - but the measured values are just coincidentally identical (a consequence of the limited input range and precision of the instruments).

What is the effect (in theory) or removing duplicates on model accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model will become less accurate.

For example, let's say you have features A and B, and you have 51 observations. For 50 of those A=10 and B=20 correspond to dependent value of 5, and you have 1 observation for which A=10 and B=20 correspond to dependent value of 100.

Without removing duplicates when making a prediction for a new observation with A=10 and B=20, Random Forest will give roughly the average of 51 values mentioned above, which is close to 6.86. If you remove duplicates you will get an average of 5 and 100 or 52.5.

And assuming your test data has the same distribution as the original data, the model will be far off on many observations. Therefore, unless you have a good reason to believe that the test data will have a different distribution, don't remove the duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer about your specific question: your model is likely to be less accurate if you just remove training data.

Moreover:

> With very large sample counts some models (like Random Forests) become very large (several GB when pickled).

It sounds like the size of your final model is the reason why you're considering pruning your dataset. Assuming you are using scikit-learn, I'd recommend looking at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and the parameters that you can tweak that impact your final model size.

Specifically, parameters like `n_estimators`, `max_depth`, `min_samples_split`, and `min_samples_leaf` all have default values that tend to generate large models. For example, `max_depth` is set to `None` and therefore (as per the docs) "nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples." If you experiment with these you are likely to be able to generate much smaller models, in terms of size-on-disk, without needing to prune your dataset.